# Xcode 9 ios 11 hidden control center?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've downloaded Xcode 9.3 beta from https://developer.apple.com/download/

I wanted to test something with the new control center and realized that I cannot see it. For some reason control center doesn't show up in my simulator 11.0(15A538e).

[image: No settings for control center]

[image: Control center is not visible on swipe from the bottom]

Is it a limitation of the similator beta or do I need to adjust some setting?

Comment: That is weird. I skimmed through the Xcode 9 release notes and don't see it mentioned as a known limitation. Control Center isn't listed in the iOS 10 simulator, but you can swipe up to get to it. What part of Control Center are you wanting to test in iOS 11?

Comment: I'm trying to test broadcasting of the whole iOS screen to a live streaming service.

Comment: Yeah from my testing @mfilimonov it looks like that requires a physical device. Hopefully Apple fixes that by the time the GM releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference.

Tested with iOS 11.3.1 - is still the same situation. It looks like it's a limitation of simulator and control center is not part of what you can test in the simulator.